# How to add dynamic qlabel

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I am not good about qt design. I want to create qlabels dynamically.

I want to create group of two qlabel with horizontal layout. And next qlabels will be added vertically.

Here is an example;

```
QLabel1  QLabel2
QLabel3  QLabel4
QLabel5  QLabel6
....
..
.
```

I want to add them with coding. And put it in `frame_result` In picture you will see frame_result has vertical layout already

[image]

Could you please help me how to do. I already spent lots of time with coding backbone of face recognition system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could dynamically add `QHBoxLayout`'s to `QFormLayout`:

```
QFormLayout *formLayout = new QFormLayout;
QHBoxLayout *hBox = new QHBoxLayout;

hBox->addWidget( new QLabel( "Label one", this ));
hBox->addWidget( new QLabel( "Label two", this ));

formLayout->addRow( hBox );
this->setLayout( formLayout );
```

Comment: There is some errors but logic is what I am looking for thank you very much

Comment: Another solution can be the usage of QTreeView with two columns and QStandrardItemModel with clickable items. Probably it will be better if you have hundreds of labels. @goGud

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov I will add image on QLabels if it is possible to add with QTreeView, your solution looks much  useful for me